# populate dropdown from Sharepoint list

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2007, drop-down-menu

I am trying to dynamically populate a dropdown list based on the information in a Sharepoint list. I know I can add the list to the page and hide it, but what I want is to populate the list using client scripting language and not have the list exist on the current page. I assume an ajx approach, but not sure how to accomplish this. I am restricted to not having SP Designer or Visual Studio. So can this be accomplished using a webpart or a simple content editer with client scripting code/ajax. If so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SharePoint 2007, you can use the [GetListCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistcollection%28v=office.12%29.aspx) method.

See:

- [Calling the SharePoint Web Services with jQuery](http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2009/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-web-services-with-jquery.aspx)
- [Using Sharepoint’s GetListCollection](http://purbayubudi.wordpress.com/2009/08/01/using-sharepoints-getlistcollection/)

Comment: This is similar to the approach I used...Thx

Comment: Is this also the best way for SP2010?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Ribbon customizations - dropdown controls, Client Object Model and JavaScript Page Components](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/02/ribbon-customizations-dropdown-controls.html). A lot of the code is for the Ribbon, but the loadCurrentWebLists and getDropdownItemsXml demonstrate what you are trying to do. You can also look at [SharePoint 2010: Use ECMAScript to manipulate (Add/Delete/Update/Get) List Items](http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.com/2010/07/sharepoint-2010-use-ecmascript-to.html) and [OM model Javascript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8602/om-model-javascript). These deal with List Items, but you should be able to adapt them for Lists.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that I am using SP 2007, will the ECMAScript idea work on that version

Comment: Also.. isnt Ribbon minimum requirements Windows 7..Most of users still on XP, so the first link idea wont  work?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation) library for 2007?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i use it for the user information list which is the list of all users with permissions to that site. The `select: function(e, ui){}` is the function which is called when you select something from the autocomplete box.

```
<link href="../css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.SPServices-0.5.8.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready (function() {
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: true,
        listName: "User Information List",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields>" +
            "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='MobilePhone' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='Picture' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='SPSResponsibility' />" +
            "<FieldRef Name='Name' />" +
            "</ViewFields>",
        completefunc: AttachMembersAutoComplete
    });
});

function AttachMembersAutoComplete(xmlResponse) {
    var domElementArray = $( "[nodeName=z:row]", xmlResponse.responseXML );

    var dataMap = domElementArray.map(function() {
        return {
            value: $(this).attr('ows_Title'),
            mobile: $(this).attr('ows_MobilePhone'),
            picture: $(this).attr('ows_Picture'),
            askmeabout: $(this).attr('ows_SPSResponsibility'),
            name: $(this).attr('ows_Name')
        };
    });

    var data = dataMap.get();

    $("input#inputMembersAutoComplete").autocomplete({
        source: data,
        select: function(e, ui){

            window.alert(ui.item['askmeabout'] + "\n" + ui.item['name']);

            if(ui.item['picture'] != undefined) {
                var tmpPicture = ui.item['picture'];
                var commaIndex = tmpPicture.indexOf(',');
                tmpPicture = tmpPicture.substr(0,commaIndex);
            }else{
                var tmpPicture = "/_layouts/images/person.gif";
            }

            var tmpHTML = "<div>";
            tmpHTML += "<a href='/Person.aspx?accountname=" + ui.item['name'] + "' >";
            tmpHTML += "<p>"+ ui.item['value'] + "  " + ui.item['mobile'] + "</p>";
            tmpHTML += "</a>";
            tmpHTML += "<img src='"+ tmpPicture + "' />";
            tmpHTML += "</div>";

            $("#person_info").html(tmpHTML);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```